# Can't get Vuex storage inside Axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

Axios init error when i'm accessing Vuex storage

```
import stores from '../stores';

const axios = require('axios');
const { message } = require('ant-design-vue');
const { MARKET_PLACE_API } = require('../../config');

const config = {
  baseURL: `${MARKET_PLACE_API}/api/v1`,
  timeout: 30000,
};

const marketPlateAPI = axios.create(config);

marketPlateAPI.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED') message.error('Timeout Request!');
    if (error.response && error.response.data.code === '002') {
      message.error('Unauthorized!');
      console.log('stores: ', store);
      await stores.dispatch('auth/logout');
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

export default { marketPlateAPI };
```

I don't know why I think that import it correctly

my vue storage file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import authStores from './auth.stores';
import appStores from './app.stores';
import uploadMainStores from './uploadMain';
import orderStores from './order.stores';
import supplierStore from './supplier.stores';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth: authStores,
    app: appStores,
    uploadMain: uploadMainStores,
    order: orderStores,
    supplier: supplierStore,
  },
});

export default store;
```

and authStore have logout actions:

```
  actions: {
    ...
    async logout({ commit, state }) {
      clearTimeout(state.timeoutID);
      await commit('deleteToken', {});
      await router.push({ name: 'SignIn' });
    },
   }
```

and I'm assigning to Vue instance

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Why I can't use my mutation inside this interceptor, what is causing issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you import Axios globbaly:

```
// app.js
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for suggest, i have try to import Axios globbaly with many ways but my bug not to fix.